# How to dynamically populate the values of a select element with a radio-button with KnockoutJS

Tags: select, radio-button, knockout.js

what I want to create is a select element that has values determined by a selection in a pair of radio-button ('parent'):

```
<p>
How many dimensions? 
<input type="radio" name="dimension" value="2D" data-bind="checked: dimSelect" />2D
<input type="radio" name="dimension" value="3D" data-bind="checked: dimSelect" />3D
</p>
<p data-bind="text: dimSelect"></p>
<p data-bind="visible: dimSelect">
Which geometry? <select data-bind="options: geometry, optionsCaption: 'Choose'"></select>
</p>
```

My viewmodel now is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function viewModel(){
    dimSelect = ko.observable();
    if (dimSelect() == '2D') {
        alert('2D: ' + dimSelect());
        geometrie = ko.observableArray(['Circle', 'Quadrant', 'Triangle']);
    } else {
        alert('3D: ' + dimSelect());
        geometrie = ko.observableArray(['Cilinder', 'Cube', 'Widge']);
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
</script>
```

But for some reason I can get the dimSelect value represented in the text binder but not in the if statement in my viewModel. It is undefined (so 3D applies).
I'm probably doing some newbie thing wrong like the entire theoretical approach, so please keep your answer as practical/understandable as possible.

Thanks for your time and patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways that you can approach this one.

In your current code, you are creating some global variables in your constructor function rather than attaching them to the new instance of the object that you are creating (`this`).

Here is another way to do it:

```
<p>
How many dimensions? 
<input type="radio" name="dimension" value="2D" data-bind="checked: dimSelect" />2D
<input type="radio" name="dimension" value="3D" data-bind="checked: dimSelect" />3D
</p>
<p data-bind="text: dimSelect"></p>
<p data-bind="with: dimSelect">
    Which geometry? <select data-bind="options: $root.dimensions[$data], optionsCaption: 'Choose'"></select>
</p>
```

js:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.dimSelect = ko.observable();
    this.dimensions = {
        '2D': ['Circle', 'Quadrant', 'Triangle'],
        '3D': ['Cilinder', 'Cube', 'Widge']         
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/dvxdR/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works, so that's great! Thank you. But perhaps you'd have answered differently if you would have known my second select element was also dependable of the dimension radio-buttons: `2D -> Surface, Perimeter ; 3D -> Surface, Volume` because you used the pluralisation system (e.g. dimension -> dimensions[$data]) I cannot use the same solution twice (right?) perhaps another of the possibilities?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, then I would move to something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7J6Dd/ where the `2D` and `3D` properties have sub-properties for the various options.

Comment: in addition, how can I use this way to access the same array in a foreach binding? `data-bind="foreach: $root.dimensions[$data].geometry"` doesn't seem to work (error: $root.dimensions[$data] is undefined)

Comment: If I had to take a guess, I would say that your issue is that you are trying to use a block-level element (as part of your `foreach` inside of a `p` tag.  Browsers will move the elements outside of the `p` and KO will error out trying to bind it against the wrong context in your example.  Change your `p` to a `div` and give it a shot.

Comment: follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794748/how-to-use-foreach-binding-knockout-js-with-the-data-object