# How to use foreach binding (knockout.js) with the $data object

Tags: foreach, knockout.js

for some reason I cannot get a foreach binding to work with a $data object in it, I have posted the code on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danieltulp/PYbzF/)

the weird thing for me is that

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'input-template', foreach: $root.geometries['Kubus'].invoer }"></div>
```

works, and that $data is 'Kubus'

but that

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'input-template', foreach: $root.geometries[$data].invoer }"></div>
```

gives a javascript error message:

> Unable to parse bindings. Message: TypeError: $root.geometries[$data]
>   is undefined; Bindings value: template: { name: 'input-template',
>   foreach: $root.geometries[$data].invoer }

1. can you explain why this happens?
2. can you tell me how I should do it so the error doesn't show?
3. are there ways to do what I'm trying to do with more efficient code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me you are being too tricky with the `with: dimSelect` and `with: geoSelect`.  Why not just use `dimSelect()` and `geoSelect()` directly?

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/PYbzF/12/

Comment: only problem with this solution is that $root.geometries[geoSelect()].invoer or .type throws an error (and brakes the page) when geoSelect is empty, worked around that with: http://jsfiddle.net/danieltulp/QRnD2/

Answer (score 0):

In case that you use $data it is an object, but not a string like 'Kubus'.

You should add new field like "name" to "geometries" and add method "getGeometryByName", where you will do something like this:

```
 self.getGeometryByName = function (geometryName) {
        var result= null;
        $.each(self.geometries(), function (index, value) {
            if (value.name() == geometryName) {
                result= value;
                return false;
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
```

Also is much easier to understand view code when you use model fields directly by name instead of *with: + $data* (from own development experience)